# How to make google play updates the apps one-by-one?

Tags: updates

How to make google play updates the apps one-by-one (in sequence).

Notes:
- Device is unrooted, and rooting is not an option.
- Auto-update is needed and updating manually is not and option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the final objective? (I thought Play Store always download and install apps in series). I mean, what lead you to ask this question?

Comment: The point is: While play is trying to update all apps in a bunch, updates get stuck in the slow connection and may finally updates nothing.

Comment: Sometimes I stop Google play or restart the device when this happens.

Comment: If you're a good programmer, you can write an app that downloads all your updates one by one and installs them. Other than that you could hack the playstore apk (check with the playstore license if this is even legal) to do what you want. Both options are incredibly hard to implement.